# Java Game: Mouse Control and border(rectangle) issue

Tags: java

The `20 x 20` box is not being displayed(including motion listener and no errors). Another class is the window which sets up the `JFrame` and game `start()`. Here is the code below(with a package called `"javagame9"` .

```
public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2713820159854096116L;
    public static final int WIDTH = 640, HEIGHT = 700;
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running = false;
    public static boolean paused = false;

    public Game() {
        this.addMouseMotionListener(new Mouse());
        new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "A Game", this);
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        running = true;
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        try {
            thread.join();
            running = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        this.requestFocus();
        long LastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int frames = 0;
        while (running) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - LastTime) / ns;
            LastTime = now;
            while (delta >= 1) {
                tick();
                delta--;
            }
            if (running)
                render();
            frames++;
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
                timer += 1000;
                System.out.println("FPS: " + frames);
                frames = 0;
            }
        }
        stop();
    }

    private void tick() {


    }


    private void render() {


    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Game();
    }
}
```

```
public class Mouse extends Canvas implements MouseMotionListener {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7986961236445581989L;

    private Image dbImage;    //Mouse - class
    private Graphics dbg;

    int mx, my;
    boolean mouseDragged;


    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
        dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
        paintComponent(dbg);
        g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        if (mouseDragged) {
            g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            g.fillRect(mx, my, 20, 20);
        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            g.fillRect(mx, my, 20, 20);
        }
        repaint();
    }


    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        mx = e.getX() - 10;
        my = e.getY() - 10;

        mouseDragged = true;

        e.consume();
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        mx = e.getX() - 10;
        my = e.getY() - 10;

        mouseDragged = false;
        e.consume();
    }

}
```

Comment: A Window is initially invisible. Have you tried setting the window to visible? 'Window window = new Window(); window.setVisible(true);'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have 2 `Canvas`: `Game` and `Mouse`.

Assuming that the `Window` class is the following (found it [here](https://gist.github.com/BrianDGLS/190d09ecaaf147c878b93ef1e30d6799#file-window-java)):

```
public class Window extends Canvas {

    public Window(int width, int height, String title, Game game) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);

        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        game.start();
    }

}
```

we see that the `Canvas` being added to the `JFrame` is the `Game` one, so it will be the one visible.

But you are only painting on the `Mouse` canvas, therefore you are not going to see anything.

You could move the paint logic from `Mouse` to `Game`, and use `Mouse` only for the `MouseMotionListener` functionality.

Modified `Game` class (differences highlighted by comments):

```
public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2713820159854096116L;
    public static final int WIDTH = 640, HEIGHT = 700;
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running = false;
    public static boolean paused = false;

    // fields previously in Mouse moved here:
    private Image dbImage;
    private Graphics dbg;

    // mouse field so we can reuse it
    private Mouse mouse;

    public Game() {
        // we create an instance of mouse and use it as MouseMotionListener
        mouse = new Mouse();
        this.addMouseMotionListener(mouse);
        new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "A Game", this);
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        running = true;
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        try {
            thread.join();
            running = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.requestFocus();
        long LastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int frames = 0;
        while (running) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - LastTime) / ns;
            LastTime = now;
            while (delta >= 1) {
                tick();
                delta--;
            }
            if (running)
                render();
            frames++;
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
                timer += 1000;
                System.out.println("FPS: " + frames);
                frames = 0;
            }
        }
        stop();
    }

    private void tick() {

    }

    private void render() {

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Game();
    }

    // paint methods previously in Mouse moved here:
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
        dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
        paintComponent(dbg);
        g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if (mouse.mouseDragged) {
            g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            g.fillRect(mouse.mx, mouse.my, 20, 20);
        }
        else {
            g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            g.fillRect(mouse.mx, mouse.my, 20, 20);
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Now from the `Mouse` class you can remove all the methods/fields used for the painting, also it no longer extends `Canvas`:

```
public class Mouse implements MouseMotionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7986961236445581989L;

    int mx, my;
    boolean mouseDragged;

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        mx = e.getX() - 10;
        my = e.getY() - 10;

        mouseDragged = true;

        e.consume();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        mx = e.getX() - 10;
        my = e.getY() - 10;

        mouseDragged = false;
        e.consume();
    }

}
```

Using these classes you should now be able to see what you are painting.